# Wordpress using get_term to retrieve slug not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, slug

I'm using the below code to try and get the slug for the current category and the parent category.

I've managed to get as far as getting the currently cat slug but the parent displays in readable text and nut slug format.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
    $parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );?>

        <?php echo do_shortcode("[ecs-list-events cat='{$term->slug}']"); ?>   

     <?php 
    echo $term->slug; 
    echo $parent->name;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently setup something like this myself. Here is the code I used to accomplish something similar:

```
<?php 
    global $post;    
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'my-custom-taxonomy-name');   
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $terms[0]->term_id, 'my-custom-taxonomy-name');
    $parent = get_term($term->parent, 'my-custom-taxonomy-name' );

    echo $parent->slug; //This will return the parent slug
?>
```

Using your code, you can accomplish this like so:

```
<?php 
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
$parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );
?>

<?php echo do_shortcode("[ecs-list-events cat='{$term->slug}']"); ?>   

<?php 
echo $term->slug; 
echo $parent->slug; //change this to "slug"
?>
```

You might just need to change "echo $parent->name;" to "echo $parent->slug;". In addition, you should review these articles to see what parameters can be returned from the [get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) and [get_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) functions.