# Wordpress- How to get term name from term_ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to retrieve term names from taxonomies for `$title`. I have come across a lot Codex functions like `get_post_meta()`, `get_the_terms()` etc, which seem to only get term name from `post_id`, which is not what I'm looking for.

How do I get term names from `term_id`?

Comment: I suppose you are using Wordpress? Please add this tag to you question at least so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: check this link : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16394/how-to-get-a-taxonomy-term-name-by-the-slug

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress using get\_term to retrieve slug not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459013/wordpress-using-get-term-to-retrieve-slug-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 37):

You may get the term name from term_id like this:

```
$term_name = get_term( $term_id )->name;
```

Explanation:
`get_term()` returns the term object and `name` is one of propeties of this object.

More details on codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

Answer (score 10):

Please try this:

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy); ?>
```

Note:

- $field => Just write `'id'` here
- $value => Place your `'term_id'` value here
- $taxonomy => write your custom taxonomy `'slug'` here

**For ex**: My custom `taxonomy slug` is '`services`' & '`term_id`' is `5`, so here is the code for retrieving `'term_name'`:

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'id', 5, 'services' ); 
echo $term->name; ?>
```

I hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: any reason not to call `get_term` directly?

Comment: @yivi I didn't said that get_term is not correct, you already told to use get_term in your comment that's why i gave another option other than get_term, if i also tell him to use get_term(), then what is the use of your comment. And the person who has asked the question should have a variety of answers to gain extra knowledge. It's no use to tell only one answer by all the users who provide answers.

Comment: No worries. Just wondering if there was a more interesting reason behind it.

Comment: @yivi Ok bro, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $term = get_term_by('term_id', '1', 'category'); 
 $name = $term->name;
```